# Rails conditional ('if') statements based on controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There might be a better way to do this, but I'm trying to make an if statement in rails, based on the current action, in a controller (this will be used in a view).

For example, if its the edit page, or the show page, etc. I'd like a different style for something - is there an if statement that can specify this?

(I need an if statement, because its used in a partial, on multiple pages).

Thanks!

Elliot

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `params` hash that is available in the controller contains `:controller` and `:action` keys, which specify the controller and action names of the request.

Therefore you could say

```
if params[:action] == "foo"
  # Show stuff for action 'foo'
elsif params[:action] == "bar"
  # Show stuff for action 'bar'
elsif ...
  # etc.
end
```

Answer (score 24):

It's not good practice IMO to have partials asking what the current controller and action names are. Think "tell, don't ask" (http://www.pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask). That is, rather than having the partial ask it's caller about its state, *tell* the partial what you want it to do.

One way to do this is by passing variables to the partial through the `locals` option:

```
<%= render :partial => "/common/toolbar", :locals => {:edit => true} %>
```

Then in the partial:

```
<% if defined?(edit) && edit %>
... stuff appropriate to edit mode
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :set_layout

  def set_layout
    case params[:action]
    when "foo"
      "foo_layout"
    when "bar"
      "bar_layout"
    ...
    else
      "default_layout"
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

hope it helps =)

Comment: That only works for the entire layout of the page though, doesn't it? Rather than an if in a partial as per the question.

Comment: i've edited the code to ApplicationController. In that case, since the actions are used throughout different controllers, it makes better sense now =)

Comment: It still just sets the layout for the page though, doesn't it?

Comment: i would suppose the partials will be used in the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use layouts for partials too:

```
<%= render :partial => 'some_partial', :layout => 'wrap_with_stuff' %>
```

If you want to work out what layout to use dynamically I'd put that in a helper.  So you'd end up with

```
# In your view

<%= render :partial => 'some_partial', :layout => layout_for_my_partial %>

# In your helper

def layout_for_my_partial
    params[:action] == 'show' ? 'show_wrapper' : 'everything_else_wrapper'
end
```

This will only work in some circumstances, but might be what you're trying to do.

See more here.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/8/3/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-partials-get-layouts