# Check conditions on the basics of action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a common partial that gets rendered with the new and edit action.

I have a field value which I want to change on the basis of the action which hits the form.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag( :questionnaire_registration_form_id, @campaign.registration_form.id, :name => 'registration_form_id')%>
```

this is a hidden field which I want to show only when I go to the edit of the page but not on the new of the page.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome !

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1330176/2128691)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried ?

```
object.new_record?
```

this will be true in case of a new object.

or may be

```
object.persisted?
```

this will be false in case of a new object.

happy coding !